# XPath local-name()

Tags: java, xpath

I have an array of xml node names

```
searchElementsXml = new String[]{"name", "id", "version", "description", "keywords", "authorInfos/authorInfo/name", "status"};
```

I found a solution to avoid the namespace prefix online by using local-name.

```
expression = "//*[local-name()=" + searchElementsXml[j] +"]/childnode";
```

How can I improve the expression string so I can also use my array element "authorInfos/authorInfo/name" ?

My current solution seem not to work, cause "/authorInfo/name" has to be behind the `]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to write a simple NamespaceContext implementation, and put qualified names in your XPath expression.

But, if you really want to keep doing it this way, you can make an XPath expression by appending each element name in the hierarchy as its own local-name() test:

```
StringBuilder exprBuilder = new StringBuilder("//");

for (String element : searchElementsXml[j].split("/")) {
    exprBuilder.append("*[local-name()='" + element + "']/");
}

exprBuilder.append("childnode");

expression = exprBuilder.toString();
```